# convert defined macro string to void*

Tags: c++

I have defined a macro as follows:

```
#define SOME_STRING  "some_string"
```

and there is a field that is of type `void*`. Hence, in order to assign the address of `"some_string"` to that field I have done this:

```
boxFixtureDef.userData = static_cast<void*>(SOME_STRING);
```

MVS 2012 did not complain, but Xcode and g++ report error: `invalid static_cast from type 'const char [12]' to type 'void*'`. What is wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: It's unusual that any pointer needs to be casted explicitly to a `void*` pointer. Is it more a `const` casting related problem maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use const_cast to remove constness.
static_cast cannot change constness of variable.

```
#include <iostream>

#define MACRO_TEXT "macro-text"

int main()
{
    void *ptr = const_cast<char*>(MACRO_TEXT);
    std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(You don't have to explicitly cast char* to void*. It will be implicitly done.)

Be careful. You're not allowed to modify the values in userData because original pointer is const char[] You can only read values from userData in this case.

Comment: what is I modify the value in userData?

Comment: For instance, some codes like, static_cast<char*>(userData)[0]='a', will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast` can't cast away constness. For that you need `const_cast`:

```
static_cast<void*>("something"); // This doesn't compile
static_cast<const void*>("something"); // This does
const_cast<void *>(static_cast<const void*>("something")); // This does, too.
```

Similarly, the implicit conversion of pointers to `void *` doesn't affect cv-qualifiers:

```
void *something = "something"; // This doesn't compile
void *something2 = const_cast<char *>("something"); // This does; the char * from the cast is implicitly converted
void *something3 = const_cast<void *>(static_cast<const void*>("something")); // This does, too, but is more verbose.
```

However, if anyone tries to actually modify what the resulting pointer points to, it's undefined behavior. So if it is ever possible that what `boxFixtureDef.userData` points to can be modified, you shouldn't do this. If not, why not just make it a `const void *`?

Answer (score 1):

This solved, but I don't know how much correct is this:

```
boxFixtureDef.userData = reinterpret_cast<void*>(const_cast<char*>(SOME_STRING);
```

Comment: reinterpret_cast is mostly used for pointer to/from integer (e.g. uintptr_t) conversion (as to reinterpret the nature), in this case you should use static_cast, or just const_cast with implicit convert to void*.

Comment: Editing answer with `static_cast`!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `(void *)(SOME_STRING)`.

Comment: That's not answering what was asked for. Using a sledge hammer, doesn't always apply for your current workpiece.

Comment: This will work, although generally speaking, it is more robust to use the least drastic possible cast out of the various casts that C++ has

Comment: @MattMcNabb It simply hides the details made from **really conscious decisions**. I'd never recommend to do so, that's simply bad advice. Just ***get it working*** isn't always the crucial point.